# Have a loop of queries or use MySQL (IN)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Which one of these two methods is faster.

Method A:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ )
    // SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $i ( run and fetch )
```

Method B:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ )
    $ids .= $i . ",";

// SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ( $ids )
```

Comment: Well it looks like you have the code and the database, benchmark it yourself, my gut tells me that using the `IN` clause will be the most performant.

Comment: lets not practice IN if records are uniform, u can use between , < > operators as well, check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if starting is 0 and ending is 10, then why not use **between** query

```
select * from tbl where  id between 0 and 10
```

i think this will be the fastest

Answer (score 1):

Method A is not recommandate at any point of time. As it will hit mysql server every time instead use IN() of mysql. With IN() you can do it in a single query and it will be faster and efficient than Method A.
And a better way of doing it as below. Using implode() you do like this:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4);
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
// SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ( $ids )
```

Comment: php syntax is not matter, method A or B is matter.

Comment: so according to your answer, multi selects also are better than single related selects ?

Comment: @aliA: updated my post. AND it also matters how you are writing your code (that is what your are asking "Which is the better way". Use inbuilt function of PHP is much better and accurate than what you have written.

Comment: @aliA: what mulit select? If you are talking about IN() than, in your case it is better than Method A

Comment: I mean, a select inside another select is better than selecting, fetching, and selecting again from result of prior select. ?

Comment: I did not see any select statement inside select?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41417/discussion-between-suresh-kamrushi-and-ali-a)

Comment: sorry, I am in office. I should go home right now. thank you for your reply.

Comment: very funny!! we are sitting idle here.

Answer (score 1):

use following method:

```
  $ids=array();
  for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ )
  {
    $ids[]=$i;
  }

  if(count($ids) > 0)
  {
    $query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (". implode(',',$ids)." )";
  }
```

[PHP Fiddle Example](http://codepad.org/5wHsbr7o)